# C++ Not detecting terminal in vscode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, terminal

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Pc32.png

[image]

I have installed both g++ and clang++ in my system, and Visual Studio Code is not detecting them automatically. When i run the program, i choose the "configure task" in terminal tab, but no terminals are showed.

I just follow all the steps in (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw)

I've tried restart vscode, but still the same result.

I am an absolute beginner in C++, just start using visual studio code. So, how to solve this problem.

Comment: restart vscode, after you change the `PATH` step.

Comment: I'm guessing you've not installed the c++ plugin

Comment: no, i've installed C++ plugin. I also restart vscode but still no terminals are showed.

Comment: You didn't follow the steps in the tutorial you linked, because those are not MSYS2 compilers. I don't know if this is what messes up compiler detection or not. But this isn't really a big deal, because once you know how to compile directly from the terminal, you can manually write `tasks.json` with the same commands.

Comment: Oh, i think i haven't saved the file, i will try later

Comment: save what file? task.json? c++ source file(s)?